# Orbreon - 2 input fields

Tags: forms, xhtml, orbeon

I've just started with Orbeon forms and cannot figure out the simplest possible thing (I guess).
I want to have two input fields : one for name, the other for surname. Here is my code :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
  xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
  xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms">
<head>
<xforms:model>
 <xforms:instance>
    <first-name xmlns=""/>
 </xforms:instance>

 <xforms:instance>
    <second-name xmlns=""/>
 </xforms:instance>
 </xforms:model>
</head>
<body>

<xforms:input ref="/first-name">
    <xforms:label>Sth</xforms:label>
</xforms:input>
<br/>
<xforms:input ref="/second-name">
    <xforms:label>Sth2</xforms:label>
</xforms:input>
</body> </html>
```

For some reason on the page I can see only the first one (first-name input field). What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Well it looks like I won't get any responses.I haven't found any explanations, I guess it's just the way it is in Orbeon. If you want to have multiple instatnces you should use xforms:group and MOST IMPORTANT FOR NEWBIE : <xforms> differs from <xf>, don't use both, just stick with one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```
<xh:html
    xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
    xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
    xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xh:head>
        <xf:model>
            <xf:instance>
                <form>
                    <first-name/>
                    <last-name/>
                </form>
            </xf:instance>
        </xf:model>
    </xh:head>
    <xh:body>
        <xf:input ref="first-name">
            <xf:label>First name:</xf:label>
        </xf:input>
        <xf:input ref="last-name">
            <xf:label>Last name:</xf:label>
        </xf:input>
    </xh:body>
</xh:html>
```